# Dynamically frame Filter condition based on conditions

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

We have separate table maintained for condition / filters. Based on the conditions, filters to be applied at base table.

here's the sample input conditional data for reference purpose

```
+-----------+-------------------+----------+------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+
val_range   |val_range_operator | val_From |  val_till  |   val_except  |  except_from |   except_till  |
+-----------+-------------------+----------+------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
            |                   |          |            |               |              |                |
100         |  =                |          |            |               |              |                |
            |                   |          |            |               |              |                |   
            | between           |   200    |    300     |               |              |                |
            |                   |          |            |               |              |                |
            | between           |   410    |    620     | 450,600,610   |              |                |
            |                   |          |            |               |              |                |
            | between           |   800    |   999      | 810,820,850   |     890      |     930        |
            |                   |          |            |               |              |                |
            | between           |   1200   |   1500     |               |     1300     |      1399      |
+-----------+-------------------+----------+------------+---------------+--------------+----------------+
```

Based on this input conditions , filter to be derived as follows.

```
Select col* 
from transaction_tbl 
where 
    val_range = 100 
    OR val_range between 200 AND 300 
    OR val_range between 410 AND 620 AND val_range not in (450,600,610) 
    OR val_range between 800 AND 999 AND val_range not in (810,820,850) AND NOT BETWEEN 890 and 930 
    OR val_range between 1200 AND 1500 AND val_range NOT BETWEEN 1300 AND 1399
```

please help me in achieving the filter query

Comment: can you please provide the sample input data in a more readable format?

Comment: now it's edited and in readable format. can you please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below sparkSQL will help you to build the where clause,

```
select 
  concat(
    '( ', 
    concat_ws(
      ') OR (', 
      collect_list(
        case when val_range_operator = '=' 
        and val_range is not null then concat_ws(' ', 'val_range', '=', val_range) when val_range_operator = 'between' 
        and val_From is not null 
        and val_till is not null 
        and val_range is null 
        and val_except is null 
        and except_from is null 
        and except_till is null then concat_ws(
          ' ', 'val_range', 'between', val_From, 
          'AND', val_till
        ) when val_range_operator = 'between' 
        and val_From is not null 
        and val_till is not null 
        and val_range is null 
        and val_except is not null 
        and except_from is null 
        and except_till is null then concat_ws(
          ' ', 'val_range', 'between', val_From, 
          'AND', val_till, 'AND', 'val_range', 
          'NOT', 'IN', '(', val_except, ')'
        ) when val_range_operator = 'between' 
        and val_From is not null 
        and val_till is not null 
        and val_range is null 
        and val_except is not null 
        and except_from is not null 
        and except_till is not null then concat_ws(
          ' ', 'val_range', 'between', val_From, 
          'AND', val_till, 'AND', 'val_range', 
          'NOT', 'IN', '(', val_except, ')', 
          'AND NOT BETWEEN', except_from, 
          'AND', except_till
        ) when val_range_operator = 'between' 
        and val_From is not null 
        and val_till is not null 
        and val_range is null 
        and val_except is null 
        and except_from is not null 
        and except_till is not null then concat_ws(
          ' ', 'val_range', 'between', val_From, 
          'AND', val_till, 'AND NOT BETWEEN', 
          except_from, 'AND', except_till
        ) end
      )
    ), 
    ' )'
  ) as filter_condition 
from 
  filter_tb
```

PS: scenarios are derived based on reference data. Please update the query if any other scenario exists.

Comment: Thank you Aravind. This really helped.. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder to form the Query at runtime depending upon the input or you can use something like QueryDSL to form the query at runtime.

http://www.querydsl.com/